# Any proof for :Sum of two perfect number never be a perfect number?

Tags: summation, perfect-numbers

I want to know if there is a proof to show that Sum of two perfect number never be a perfect number  by the way if there are a finitely many perfects numbers which they are sum of two perfect numbers ?

Comment: Partial answer: per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number, every even perfect number ends in 1 to base 9 (except for 6, which ends in 6). Therefore two even perfect numbers sum to 2, 7, or 3 in base 9; none of those can be perfect.

Comment: @PatrickStevens assuming odd perfect numbers don't exist, this sounds like an acceptable answer at MSE...

Comment: @draks... why'd you assume odd perfect numbers don't exist? The fact that we haven't found one says nothing. We might just not have looked hard enough

Comment: we have even +even = even we don't need to assume odd

Comment: @vrugtehagel I don't but. let an answer start with "Assuming odd perfect numbers don't exist...". Do you really expect a proof of existence on MSE?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to know whether or not odd numbers exist to prove that the sum of two perfect numbers can not again be a perfect number.

Comment: Fisrt, I don't think the statement is true. In general, a composite number N can be written as the sum of the squares if and only if all its prime factors of form 4k+3 occur an even number of times. So as an example 2430=2^2*3^2*5*13 can be written as the sum of two squares, beacuse there is one factor in form 4k+3, the 3 and it occurs two times. Hence, for every positive integer K, the number 3^2*2^{2K} can be written as sum of two squares.

Comment: @LeoGardner: A number $n$ is perfect if $\sigma(n)=2n$, where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of the divisors of $n$.  So for example, $6$ is perfect since $\sigma(6)=1+2+3+6=12=2\cdot{6}$.  Note that *squares* cannot be perfect.  (I think you are confusing the terms *perfect powers* and *perfect numbers* here - they mean different things.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is answered in the negative (for even perfect numbers) in the following answer to a closely related MSE question:

[Do there exist two perfect numbers $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that $N_1 + N_2$ is also perfect?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1468845/28816)